# Interpretation of a GAM's GCV as MSE of prediction?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I want to know whether generalized crossvalidation score (as defined on p. 179 of Wood's (2006) Generalized Additive Models - An Introduction with R) could be interpreted as an estimate of the mean square prediction error.

My motivation is that I want to compare validation errors from GAMs across different datasets, where the validation sets all reflect a specific condition. So I'd like to scale the validation errors by the standard error of prediction and combine them to assess whether the validation condition affects the quality of the GAM's predictions, *relative to how well it predicts on the calibration dataset*. Rather than doing computationally-intensive crossvalidation on the calibration set I thought I'd just use GCV. Is this an appropriate use of GCV?